# Modern equivalent of $InternetProxyRules

Tags: undocumented, networking

The undocumented symbol `$InternetProxyRules` was useful for debugging network connectivity issues. In Mathematica 12.0 it returns a list with keys "UseProxy", "HTTP", "HTTPS", "FTP", "Socks" and "UseWPAD". Since Mathematica 12.1 this symbol is no longer there.

Is there a new way of getting this information in newer versions of Mathematica?

Comment: Try ``PacletManager`$InternetProxyRules`` instead.

Comment: Thanks Carl. Feel free to put it in an answer. Also, after I made the question I found about the experimental $DefaultProxyRules (introduced in 12.1) which is pretty much the same but returns an association instead of a list.